# How can i parse this xml in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, jquery-mobile

I need to parse in JavaScript an XML received from a REST webservice, with the format below, and put the information in a grid to show it on a web page. I look for a few examples, but, this format of XML is not the typical...
Can someone help me please? Only need a point to start....

Many thanks!

```
<root tablename="center">
  <row>
    <row_attribute name="cod">1100</row_attribute>
    <row_attribute name="nom">name1</row_attribute>
    <row_attribute name="cod2">TGN</row_attribute>
  </row>
  <row>
    <row_attribute name="cod">1200</row_attribute>
    <row_attribute name="nom">name2</row_attribute>
    <row_attribute name="cod2">TGT</row_attribute>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: is the XML really this broken? `< /row_attribute>` is not a valid end tag and neither is `</row_attribute` without a `>`?

Comment: If the web service is returning malformed XML I'm not sure what you can do about it.

Comment: Is the posted code really the exact output of the web service? There are missing angle brackets in line #4 and #5.

Comment: If you want privacy do not do any critical changes, simply do just enough replacing that privacy is retained but so that nothing meaningful is changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for this. It uses the underlying browser XML parser and gives you back an object that can be searched using jQuery methods.

Comment: Better still : mention dataType: "xml" in the AJAX call.